# issues diffing JSON (twitter API)

Tags: python, json, twitter, diff

I'm working on a fairly simple script that monitors and archive's a given users tweets -- right now, my configuration requests an account's 20 most recent tweets (API limit) every five minutes, then checks to see which of those are new, and appends the new ones to a file. should be simple.

all I'm doing right now is the following loop, with u being defined as the json output from the twitter api:

```
json_u = json.loads(u)
after first run:
  q = [x for x in json_u if x not in old_u]
  write q
old_u = json_u
wait five minutes
```

problem is that the q = line doesn't seem to be doing the job right, as the q variable ends up containing all 20 new tweets every time. thinking that python was having a hard time with this construction (json_u should be a list of 20 dicts), I wanted to implement it this way instead:

```
q = [x for str(x) in json_u if str(x) not in old_u]
```

but it throws a 
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call error.

any help? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is [ expression for variables in ... ], this is why you get the syntax error.

Your original list comprehension was fine. The problem seems to be that the dicts you have in jason_u are not identical to those in old_u.

Have you printed the dicts and looked for differences such as timestamps?

Comment: that doesn't make logical sense to me though -- I don't want q to contain a list of strings (a list of dicts is just fine with me), I want it to /compare/ strings -- or somehow get around its apparent inability to properly compare dicts.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't read your problem description thoroughly enough, my bad. Revised it now, maybe it's more helpful.

Comment: The API limit is 100 not 20 by the way.

Comment: I have printed the dicts, and there are no timestamps -- that was my first guess -- so I'm really stumped here. will see if I'm missing anything obvious...

Comment: oh, duh -- of course. the statuses_count variable is incremented every time the account's actually tweeted more, and more often than not that's happened in between my checks, causing this comparison to fail. is there any easy way to do a diff on json that ignores certain parameters?

Comment: serilain, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480806/compare-dictionaries-ignoring-specific-keys