# ignoring an element from a dict when asserting in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I was wondering if there is a way to ignore an element in a dict when doing an assert in pytest.  We have an assert which will compare a list containing a last_modified_date.  The date will always be updated so there is no way to be sure that the date will be equal to the date originally entered.

For example:

```
{'userName':'bob','lastModified':'2012-01-01'}
```

Thanks
Jay

Comment: Can you mock your datasource so that your list contains known values?

Answer (score 22):

I solved this issue by creating object that equals to everything:

```
class EverythingEquals:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

everything_equals = EverythingEquals()

def test_compare_dicts():
    assert {'userName':'bob','lastModified':'2012-01-01'} == {'userName': 'bob', 'lastModified': everything_equals}
```

This way it will be compared as the same and also you will check that you have `'lastModified'` in your dict.

EDIT:

Now you can use [`unittest.mock.ANY`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.ANY) instead of creating your own class.

Comment: Nice solution, and I like how it checks that the key is there, too. I made it less verbose, with `everything_equals = type('omnieq', (), {"__eq__": lambda x, y: True})()`.

Answer (score 21):

There is an excellent symbol called [`ANY`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any) in the system library [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) that can be used as a wildcard. Try this

```py
from unittest.mock import ANY
actual = {'userName':'bob', 'lastModified':'2012-01-01'}
expected = {'userName':'bob', 'lastModified': ANY}
assert actual == expected
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the `dict` and remove the `lastModified` key from the copy, or set it to a static value, before asserting. Since `del` and `dict.update()` and the like don't return the `dict`, you could write a helper function for that:

```
def ignore_keys(d, *args):
    d = dict(d)
    for k in args:
        del d[k]
    return d

assert ignore_keys(myDict, "lastModified") == {"userName": "bob")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def test_compare_dicts():
    dict1 = {'userName':'bob','lastModified':'2012-01-01'}
    dict2 = {'userName':'bob','lastModified':'2013-01-01'}

    excluded_fields = ['lastModified']

    assert {k: v for k, v in dict1.items() if k not in excluded_fields} == {k: v for k, v in dict2.items() if k not in excluded_fields}
```