# Is there anyway to wildcard field values while comparing two json objects in python?

Tags: python, json

I want to compare two json objects in python:

Expected output

```
   "expected":
   {
       "result": [
           {
               "code": 8100, 
               "message": "Process EASD1 has been added"
           }
       ]
  }
```

Actual Output

```
   "actual":
   {
       "result": [
           {
               "code": 8100, 
               "message": "Process EASD has been added"
           }
       ]
   }
```

Is there any way that we can use wild card for "message" field value since for me the process name will be different everytime.

Comment: Why don't you just compare the code then?

Comment: Set the `'message'` field to a constant value before comparison

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480806/compare-dictionaries-ignoring-specific-keys

Comment: I need a similar code for writing a JSON input and output interpreter