# Difference between two lists of dictionaries ignoring certain keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to find the difference between two lists of dictionaries by comparing only certain keys of the dictionaries.

```
a = [
    {"fruit": "apple", "colour": "green", "notes":"one a day"},
    {"vegetable": "tomato", "colour": "red", "origin": "asia"}
]

b = [
    {"fruit": "apple", "colour": "green", "origin": "central asia"},
    {"fruit": "strawberry", "colour": "red", "notes":"vitamin c"}
]
```

In the example I would like to ignore `notes` and `origin` in the comparison logic but still keep them in the output. Expected outcome:

```
output = [
    {"vegetable": "tomato", "colour": "red", "origin": "asia"},
    {"fruit": "strawberry", "colour": "red", "notes":"vitamin c"}
]
```

I've tried to use `in` condition but it compares all the dictionaries keys:

```
difference = [i for i in a if i not in b]
```

I've tried to adapt this solution, but the problem it compares individual dictionary entries and not the whole set:

> [Compare dictionaries ignoring specific keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480806/compare-dictionaries-ignoring-specific-keys)

```
def equal_dicts(a, b):
    ignore_keys = ("notes", "origin")
    ka = set(a).difference(ignore_keys)
    kb = set(b).difference(ignore_keys)
    return ka == kb and all(a[k] == b[k] for k in ka)

 for item in a:
        if not equal_dicts(a, b):
            print('same dictionary')
```

Comment: but your expected outcome contains `"notes"`, how that?

Comment: Yes I would like the comparison logic not to include the key but the outcome to keep it. I'll update the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
def list_diff(a, b):
    return [a_item for a_item in a if not any(equal_dicts(a_item, b_item) for b_item in b)]

output = list_diff(a, b) # Everythin that's in a but not in b
output.extend(list_diff(b, a)) # Everythin that's in b but not in a
```

Which gives you:

```py
output = [
  {'vegetable': 'tomato', 'colour': 'red', 'origin': 'asia'}, 
  {'fruit': 'strawberry', 'colour': 'red', 'notes': 'vitamin c'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first filter out the keys you want to ignore, then compare dictionaries normally.

If you still want the ignored keys to be included in the comparison result, this approach would need to be modified a bit - e.g. compare the filtered result to the original `a` and `b` and add the missing fields.

```
ignored_keys = {'notes', 'origin'}
filtered_a = [{k:v for k,v in sub_dict.items() if k not in ignored_keys} for sub_dict in a]
filtered_b = [{k:v for k,v in sub_dict.items() if k not in ignored_keys} for sub_dict in b]
```

Then the differences are:

```
in_a_not_b = [elem for elem in filtered_a if elem not in filtered_b]
in_b_not_a = [elem for elem in filtered_b if elem not in filtered_a]
full_diff = in_a_not_b + in_b_not_a
```

As for ignored keys, I'd probably add them before merging the results because we know where the result is coming from...

---

Or the lazy version without much thinking (as in: there may be more efficient/smart way of doing this but I like dict/list comprehensions and hate "manual" loops): make a mapping from the filtered thing to the original dict.

Dicts are not hashable but we can make our filtered "dicts" into tuples of pairs:

```
ignored_keys = {'notes', 'origin'}
filtered_a = {tuple((k,v) for k,v in sub_dict.items() if k not in ignored_keys):sub_dict for sub_dict in a}
filtered_b = {tuple((k,v) for k,v in sub_dict.items() if k not in ignored_keys):sub_dict for sub_dict in b}

#compare on keys but get the original as the result
in_a_not_b = [filtered_a[elem] for elem in filtered_a if elem not in filtered_b]
in_b_not_a = [filtered_b[elem] for elem in filtered_b if elem not in filtered_a]
full_diff = in_a_not_b + in_b_not_a
```

Result:

```
>>> full_diff
[{'vegetable': 'tomato', 'colour': 'red', 'origin': 'asia'}, {'fruit': 'strawberry', 'colour': 'red', 'notes': 'vitamin c'}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'll try it now.